# using where in mysql query when populating jtree from DB

Tags: java

I'm populating jtree from mysql DB which is working fine but my problem is that when i use select .... where condition is then the condition after where ... is ignored and the tree is populated with all data from the table!

```
 public void PopoultateTree(){
    try {


        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        list.add("Chart of Accounts");

        String sql = "select * from accounts where AccountCompanyCode = '" + General.BaseForm.LoggedCompanyCode + "' and AccountFinYear = '" + CompanyData[1] + "'";

        con = ConnectDataBase.ConnectDataBase_Method();  // receive the DB connection from another general class
        statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rslt = statement.executeQuery();

        while (rslt.next()){

            Object value[] = {rslt.getString("AccountName")};
            list.add(value);


        }
        Object hierarchy[] = list.toArray();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = processHierarchy(hierarchy);

        DefaultTreeModel treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
        ChartOfAccountsTree.setModel(treeModel);

        // expand the tree 
        for (int i = 0; i < ChartOfAccountsTree.getRowCount(); i++) {
          ChartOfAccountsTree.expandRow(i);
        }

        disconnect();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ChartOFAccountsDisplay.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've a suggestion, before executing the query, just print `sql` to see if the query that you're executing is correct

Comment: I did and it's correct

Comment: Could you post the query here?

Comment: String sql = "select * from accounts where AccountCompanyCode = '" + General.BaseForm.LoggedCompanyCode + "' and AccountFinYear = '" + CompanyData[1] + "'";

Comment: the query looks like "select * from accounts where AccountCompanyCode = '2' and accountFinYar = '2019-2019'"

Comment: unitl i get a solution I've just copied the required data to a temporary table and buidl the jTree from that table